# Recurrent Javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

I have an annoying problem, i have trying to implement a simple 10 or 15 minute recurrent countdown. i have tried jQuery but it just gives me options to count down to a date and stops after the countdown is finished.

I found the below code [Here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=45319) but i cant figure it to remove the days and make it to count down for 10 or 15 minuters. Can someone please help me?

```
<div id="countre3">Loading...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function mycountre(o, timeArray){
         var countre = document.getElementById(o);
         if(!countre) {
             return;
         }

         // helper functions
         function mksec(day, h, m, s){ return day*24*60*60+h*60*60+m*60+s; }
         function toTimeString(sec, showZero){
             var d=Math.floor(sec/(60*60*24))
             var h=Math.floor(sec/(60*60)%24);
             var m=Math.floor((sec/60) % 60);
             var s=sec % 60;
             var ret=d+'days '+h+'hrs '+m+'min '+s+'sec';
             if(showZero){
                return ret;
             }else if(d==0 && h==0 && m==0){
                return s+'sec';
             }else if(d==0){
                return h+'hrs '+m+'min '+s+'sec';
             }else if(d==0 && h==0){
                return m+'min '+s+'sec';
             }else {
                return ret;
             }
         }
         //
         var secArray = [];
         var dayNow = new Date().getDay();
         for(var i=0;i<timeArray.length;i++){
            var day=timeArray[i][0];
            if(day==-1){
                day=dayNow;
            }
             secArray.push({
                day: timeArray[i][0],
                sec: mksec(day, timeArray[i][2], timeArray[i][2], timeArray[i][3]),
                msg: timeArray[i][4] || false,
                showZero: timeArray[i][5] || false
             });
         }
         secArray.sort(function(a,b){ return a.sec-b.sec;});

         // timer code - will be called around each second (~1000 ms)
         function updatecountre(){
             // get current UTC time in seconds
             var d=new Date();
             var secNow = mksec(d.getDay(), d.getUTCHours(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds());
             // find next event
             var nextIndex=0;
             for(var i=0;i<secArray.length; i++){
                 var diff = secArray[i].sec-secNow;
                 if(diff>0){
                     nextIndex=i;
                     break;
                 }
             }
             //
             var diff=secArray[nextIndex].sec-secNow;
             var prevDiff=diff;
             if(diff<0){
                var dayDiff = 6-secArray[nextIndex].day;
                if(secArray[nextIndex].day == -1){
                    dayDiff=0;
                }
                diff=(dayDiff+1)*24*60*60-Math.abs(diff);
             }
             var str='';
             // get message if there is any set
             if(secArray[nextIndex].msg){
                 str=secArray[nextIndex].msg;
             }
             var timeString = toTimeString(diff, secArray[nextIndex].showZero);
             if(str.match('@{countre}')!=null){
                 str=str.replace(/@{countre}/, timeString);
             }else if(str.indexOf(' ')==0){ // message starts with space
                 str=timeString+str;
             }else{ // no specific hint where to put countre, so display it after message
                 str+=timeString;
             }
             countre.innerHTML=str;
        }

         setInterval(updatecountre, 1000);

     };
mycountre('countre3', [ [5, 5, 0, 0, '<center><b>Next Turns are Due in </b><p class="smalltext"> @{countre}</center>', false] ]);
</script>
```

Comment: This script seems to achieve what you're looking for: http://webdevel.blogspot.com/2004/10/countdown-javascript.html in a simpler way.

Comment: the above script resets on refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    function mycountre(countdownId, countdownSeconds, countdownLooping){
    var countre = document.getElementById(countdownId); // get html element
    if (!countre) {
        return;
    }

    var target = new Date().getTime() + 1000 * countdownSeconds; // target time
    var intervalId; // id of the interval

    // update function
    function updatecountre(){
        var time = Math.floor((target - new Date().getTime()) / 1000); // countdown time in seconds
        if (time < 0) { // if countdown ends
            if (countdownLooping) { // if it should loop
                target += 1000 * countdownSeconds; // set new target time
                time = Math.floor((target - new Date().getTime()) / 1000); // recalculate current time
            } else { // otherwise
                clearInterval(intervalId); // clear interval
                time = 0; // set time to 0 to avoid displaying negative values
            }
        }

        // split time to seconds, minutes and hours
        var seconds = '0' + (time % 60);
        time = (time - seconds) / 60;
        var minutes = '0' + (time % 60);
        time = (time - minutes) / 60;
        var hours = '0' + time;

        // make string from splited values
        var str = hours.substring(hours.length - 2) + ':' + minutes.substring(minutes.length - 2) + ':' + seconds.substring(seconds.length - 2);
        countre.innerHTML = str;
    }

    intervalId = setInterval(updatecountre, 200); // start interval to execute update function periodically
};
mycountre(
    'countre3', // id of the html element
    15 * 60, // time in seconds (15min here)
    true // loop after countdown ends?
);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xv3jx/1/

Comment: +1. Note that the OP wants a "recurrent countdown", so at the point where you test for the time being less than zero you might want to restart the count (otherwise call `clearInterval()`). Also, you can get a smoother appearance if you set the interval for something significantly less than a second, say 50 or 100ms, because the browser doesn't necessarily call your function exactly at the requested interval.

Comment: i can see your example working just fine on js fiddle but im having a little hard time implementing it.

Comment: I add some comments to the code. I also made some minor changes after @nnnnnn comments

Comment: @Lolo , i see your changes, im still having trouble displaying it. How are you displaying it?

Comment: As you can see in the demo on jsfiddle, you must create html tag with some id and pass this id to the function. In demo there is `<div>` with id `countre3` which is passed to the function as first argument.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">...</javascript>` and <div id="countre3"></div>

Comment: @Lolo, That script still resets on page refresh.

Comment: Of course it does, it's JS. There is no single word in the question which tells it shouldn't. You can use cookies to store per user state of that counter, or database/file on server to have global state. Here is example with cookies: http://jsfiddle.net/Xv3jx/3/

Answer (score 1):

Small attempt for a jQuery plugin - more generic without minute/hour calc to avoid that the exaple gets too big:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.countdown = function(params) {
        this.each(function() { 
            container = $.extend({
                t: $(this),
                stepSize: 1000, // milliseconds
                duration: 3600, // seconds
                offset: 0,
                stepCallback: function() {},
                finishCallback: function() {},
                interval: function() {
                    if (this.offset>this.duration) {
                        this.finishCallback();
                    } else {
                        this.stepCallback();
                    }
                    this.offset += this.stepSize/1000;
                }
            }, params);
            setInterval(function() {
                container.interval();
            }, container.stepSize);
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Can be used with:

```
$('.main').countdown({
    stepCallback: function() { console.log('step');}, 
    finishCallback: function() { console.log('done');} 
});
```

A simple countdown would then be implemented like this:

```
$('.main').countdown({
    duration: 300,
    stepCallback: function() {
        var time = this.duration-this.offset
        var seconds = '0' + (time % 60);
        time = (time - seconds) / 60;
        var minutes = '0' + (time % 60);
        time = (time - minutes) / 60;
        var hours = '0' + time;
        var str = hours.substring(hours.length - 2) + ':' + minutes.substring(minutes.length - 2) + ':' + seconds.substring(seconds.length - 2);
        $(this.t).html(str);
    }, 
    finishCallback: function() {  $(this.t).html('tadaaa'); } 
});
```

Cheers