# javascript timer loop

Tags: javascript, timer

I want to create a timer that once it reaches a certain point, the timer resets, and then  starts over.

Right now, I've got the loop set up, and as a test I want it to reset after 5000 ms (5 seconds). But the counter goes all haywire.

WIP Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/stursby/wUHA3/

Comment: Before I click the demo, will it crash my browser? `:P`

Comment: The counter does reset in Firefox...

Comment: haha no, it's not an infinite loop. I'm updating the text of a span with the current timer value... so that's the only thing that gets messed up, you'll see.

Comment: You may like to look at the code from this question's accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634415/recurrent-javascript-countdown

Comment: not sure if IE supports it, but `Date.now()` is a bit cleaner than `new Date().getTime()`

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Instead of setTimeout, consider using setInterval. It will repeat automatically until you clear the interval.

```
setInterval(myMethod, 5000);

function myMethod( )
{
  //this will repeat every 5 seconds
  //you can reset counter here
}
```

Comment: I agree, just to point out the reason he is having the issue described is because of the line `var diff = (new Date().getTime() - start) - time;` there is no need for that line. He should be doing `window.setTimeout(instance, 100);` instead of `window.setTimeout(instance, (100 - diff));`. And his issue is resolved.

Comment: You could post that as an answer because it's just as valid. OP can then decide if that method might suit their overall program. Whilst setInterval usually makes sense in a case like this, your code directly fixes the issue at hand.

Comment: For completeness, to set the interval: `var timer = setInterval(function(){ doStuff() }, 1000);` To subsequently clear the interval (and stop the timer): `clearInterval(timer);`

Answer (score 6):

I agree with keyboardP that you should probably be using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. However, to answer your original question the reason you are having issues with the timer is because of your repetition logic. Don't use:

```
var diff = (new Date().getTime() - start) - time;
window.setTimeout(instance, (100 - diff));
```

You don't need to try and account for execution time (which I assume is what you were trying to do with `diff`). Just assume it is negligible and use:

```
setTimeout(instance, 100);
```

And your issue is resolved, as you can see in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUHA3/2/).

Comment: is there an easy way for this to increment by 1's instead of 100's? For example, 2.1 seconds is 2100, is there a way to get to more decimals like 2.154 seconds, or 2154 on the timer?

Comment: well the accuracy will not be exact to the millisecond. Browsers evaluate timeouts/intervals differently. As an average every 13ms a timeout is evaluated. SO that is about as specific as you can get, depending on the browser.

Comment: Okay, well I won't need to visually display the timer in ms, I just want the accuracy of 4 decimal places, because the timer is going to trigger other events that will need to synch up based on the timer and 2.4 seconds (2400 versus 2418) makes a difference.

here's a WIP demo http://jsfiddle.net/stursby/zFYUT/5/ I still need to add looping, but that's essential what I'm trying to do (in the end, it won't be visual though)

Comment: Like I said, timeouts and intervals are evaluated differently in each browser. Usually around every 14ms they are evaluated. Meaning, if you do a delay of 1ms, it may actually take anywhere from 1 to 15. so your timer will not be accurate to a millisecond. Probably not even to 10ms, but it would be pretty close in orders of 100ms. Best you can do is if you have to trigger an event at 2418, you trigger it once the time ellapsed has *exceeded* 2418; thats about the best you can do.