# simple loop with append() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-mobile

The function `StartScan()` is called trough a button-click and `addDevices()` creates the output dynamically. I want this output every 2 or 5 seconds automatically updated.

In the console I see that the function `StartScan()` reloads automatically, so the values are there and I just have put the `addDevice()` function in a loop.

Where am I wrong?

```
function startScan()
{
    var paramsObj = {serviceUuids:[]};

    console.log("Start Scan : " + JSON.stringify(paramsObj));

    bluetoothle.startScan(startScanSuccess, startScanError, paramsObj);

    return false;
}

function startScanSuccess(obj)
{
    console.log("Start Scan Success : " + JSON.stringify(obj));     

    if (obj.status == "scanResult")
    {
        console.log("Scan Result");

        addDevice(obj.address, obj.name, obj.rssi);
    }
    else if (obj.status == "scanStarted")
    {
        console.log("Scan Started");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Unexpected Start Scan Status");
    }
}

function addDevice(address, name, rssi)
{
        var $devices = $(".devices");

        var $check = $devices.find("li[data-address='{0}']".format(address));

        if ($check.length > 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        var template = $("#device").text().format(address, name, rssi);

        $devices.append(template);
        $devices.trigger("create");

        window.setTimeout(50000);
        console.log("Loop: " + i);

        if (rssi < -100){   
            alert(name + " lost proximity");
        }

        setInterval( function(){ addDevice(adress, name, rssi);}, 2000);    
}
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery please add the tag to your question.

Comment: What is `format()`? Are you sure it returns the jQuery object?

Comment: Note: [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) expects a function to call along with the timeout. It isn't an equivalent to `sleep()` functions that pause the current thread, delaying following code. It just delays calling the function that's provided to it.

Comment: `setTimeout(50000)` is totally useless. Javascript is asynchronous, it will launch the timeout and keep going with the code in the meantime, while the timeout counts.

Comment: You're probably looking for something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663246/javascript-timer-loop

Comment: @George Yes I'm sure. format() ist just a simple format method to change the values to strings

Comment: @Jeremy Thille apart from my wrong use of setTimeout() the loop is still not working. Could there be another reason?

Comment: Did you see my answer below?

Comment: @Cerbrus yea, kind of. I already edited my addDevice function and changed setTimeout to setInterval and tried different variations, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want :

```
function addDevice(address, name, rssi)
{
        var $devices = $(".devices");
.....   
}

setInterval( addDevice, 2000); // without arguments
setInterval( function(){ addDevice(address, name, rssi) }, 2000); // with arguments
```

This will launch the `addDevice` function every 2 seconds.

Comment: Define "not working". It's very vague. Do you have errors in the console? What if you console.log stuff? How do you know if the function is called or not? etc.

Comment: There are no error in the console.log, quiet the contrary trough the console.log("Start Scan : " + JSON.stringify(paramsObj)) I see on the console exactly that what I want to see on the screen. The addDevice function is called once, but I want it to repeat, like the startscan function does.

Comment: I have added a variant to my code to launch the function with arguments, try this?

Comment: You don't have to be sorry. But as I said earlier, "It's not working" isn't helpful at all. It just indicates me that it's not working, and does not give a clue about how to debug this and make it work.

Comment: nothing changed - it's like it ignores the setInterval(), but there are still no errors and the App works like before.